# Trying to postpone an API call until a batch call is completed with RXJS

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have large list of events, which have an associated additional info related to them, which requires computations and is overall quite heavy backend progress. So I first populate the events and fetch the additional data in a batch. I try to first look into the batch and see, if the associated data is there, if not I will fetch it on need-basis. I try to avoid this by using a Behaviorsubject (linksReady) to track when I am fetching the batch and when it is finished.

```js
 getLinksFromApi() {
   this.linksReady.next(false);
   this.api.getBatchData(searchdefinitions).subscribe(res => {
   this.Links = res;
   this.linksReady.next(true);
});}
```

Then, when this ready I search this array:

```js
getLinkForEventDirect(id:number):Observable<RegisterLinksDto> {

    let temp = this.Links.find(x => x.id === id);
    if (temp == null) {
      return this.api.getLinkById(id);
    } else {
      return of(temp);
    }
```

This works fine, as long as I surround all the async-pipes which use the getLinkForEventDirect as a source with the observable from linksReady, but this is cumbersome and feels quite clunky. What I tried to do is following

```js
getLinkForEvent(id:number):Observable<RegisterLinksDto> {
    return this.linksReady$.pipe(
      switchMap((x) => {
        if (x === true){
          return this.getLinkForEventDirect(id);
        } else {
          return EMPTY;
        }
      },
      ));
  }
```

Which with my tests seems to have the same effect as wrapped async-pipes.

Questions:

1. Is there a better way to do this with RXJS?
2. Could I make getLinkForEventDirect simpler?
3. Is the EMPTY correct return observable in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

Create an observable that cashes a value via shareReplay. Start the observable immediately (so it's cashed as soon as possible). Then use that observable to return a link sometime later.

```ts
batchData$: Observable<RegisterLinksDto[]>;

constructor(){
  this.batchData$ = this.api.getBatchData(searchdefinitions).pipe(shareReplay(1));
  this.batchData$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe();
}

getLinkForEventDirect(id:number): Observable<RegisterLinksDto> {
  return this.batchData$.pipe(
    take(1),
    switchMap(links => {
      const temp = links.find(x => x.id === id);
      if (temp == null) {
        return this.api.getLinkById(id);
      } else {
        return of(temp);
      }
    )
  );
}
```